# How to exclude auditd messages from dmesg and only log them in /var/log/audit.log

Tags: audit, dmesg, linux-audit

I use `audit` to log suspicious user actions on a workstation in my institution.  I found that, in addition to logging to `/var/log/audit.log`, `auditd` also writes to `/var/log/messages`.  Consequently, unprivileged user can view the logged record simply by typing the `dmesg` command.  This greatly affects user privacy.

I've tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241552/how-to-disable-useless-audit-success-log-entries-in-dmesg) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116667/dmesg-filled-with-audits-every-minute-from-cron), but instead of completely removing `audit`, I want it to still log to `/var/log/audit.log`.

I've also tried [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1227379#c37): writing `:programname, isequal, "audit" ~` to `rsyslog.conf`, but it did not work for me.

Some also suggest adding `audit=0` to kernel parameter.  I'm not sure if it shall disable `auditd` completely.  Furthermore, the workstations have many active users and should not be rebooted.

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance!

OS: Debian Testing 
auditctl version: 2.4.5

Answer (score 1):

Logging to /var/log/messages does happen at the same time as /var/log/messages. audit=0 will disable all audit logs period. That shouldn't stop auditing period though. Consider using `auditctl -e 0` also.

The audit logs that show up aren't really a "privacy concern", because if a user really wanted to know what's going on, they'd need `ausearch` and other `au*` commands to view the content of the logs/reports as they come up (hint, they need root). The audit logs will show the executed command among other things, but nothing beyond that (switches, other files, etc).

As a side note, there's also the `ps` command. Any user can see what another user is running anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answering ( :  but `auditctl -e 0` will disable everything